# ASP.NET MVC3 RAZOR: Retrieving Hidden field Attribute value in Controller (using ViewModel)

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view that has two buttons(“First” and “Second”) and one hidden field. When user clicks on “First” button, hidden field will be set as the value of “data-myAttribute” attribute in the first button. When user clicks on “Second” button, hidden field will be set as the value of “data-myAttribute” attribute in the second button. Once the hidden field is set, the form need to be submitted. This much is working fine with the following code.  Further, I need to be able to see the value of the hidden field in the controller. How do we get the value in controller?

```
namespace MyHiddenFieldTest.Controllers
{
public class ElementController : Controller
{

    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string ControlName { get; set; }
    }

    // GET: 
    public ActionResult MyElement()
    {
        MyViewModel myViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        return View(myViewModel);
    } 


    // POST:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyElement(MyViewModel theViewModel)
    {
        string selectedControl = theViewModel.ControlName;
        return View(theViewModel);

    }


}
}
```

VIEW

```
@model MyHiddenFieldTest.Controllers.ElementController.MyViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "MyElement";
}

<h2>MyElement</h2>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"     type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function () 
{

    $('#mainDiv input[type="button"]').on('click', function () 
    {
        $('#from').val($(this).attr('data-myAttribute'));

        alert($('#from').val());
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });

});


</script>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div id="mainDiv">
    <input type="button" value="First" data-myAttribute="theFirst"  />
    <input type="button" value="Second" data-myAttribute="theSecond"  />
    <input type="hidden" id="from" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="to" value="2" />
</div>

}
```

READING

1. [Passing JSON data from controller action to a razor view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360354/passing-json-data-from-controller-action-to-a-razor-view)

Comment: Just wondering why there is a "-1". [But I respect the freedom for expressing your opinion.]. PLease let me know if it is a duplicate of any other question or anything not suitable for this forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.Net MVC automatically binds action parameters to form posts.
Just add a `string from` parameter to the action method.

However, you will also need to `name=""` the inputs in order for the browser to submit them.

---

Actually, however, your entire script is unnecessary.

Just write

```
<input type="submit" name="from" value="First" />
<input type="submit" name="from" value="Second" />
```

The browser will submit the name / value pair of whichever button was clicked.

Comment: Can't we get it as a part of ViewModel?

Comment: @Lijo: Sure.  Just add a property.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when I changed to ' <input type="hidden" id="from" name="from" value="1" />" and following your suggestion. Thanks for the clear explanation too.